# Is it normal to have a Ruby process always running in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, phusion-passenger, rvm

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with Apache2, RVM (For Ruby) and Passenger (mod_rails).

When I look at the "top" application, I always notice the same Ruby process consuming about 1/4 of the memory on my server.

I'm just wondering if this is normal for my current setup. I'm not sure if it has to do with Passenger or RVM or if a Ruby process is just stuck. I'd appreciate any clarification this this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mod_rails` works like any other scripted language module (`mod_python` for example) this ruby process is kept alive to provide an interpreter to it, instead of spawning an interpreter per request (slow and costly) so saving resources and making things way faster.

**EDIT:** I did Passenger's documentation a read and [this is a good](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerSpawnMethod) explanation on your running ruby process. There is a link on that documentation to the advanced explanation that is very good too.